# How to claim Simoleon Token using Parity

Tags: parity, tokens

This morning, I found 10,000 Simoleon in my parity wallet.  I found this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/768oh6/a_weird_token_has_appeared_on_all_my_addresses/) which helped me to understand that this is an airdrop token from EA games for use in the SIMs.

One post says that you can claim your token by transferring them. How do I activate / claim these tokens using Parity?

and

Where am I supposed to transfer them to?

Comment: Note that there's no real evidence yet that this really has anything to do with EA or SIMs - anyone can create a token with any name.

Comment: It's a spam token, don't claim it. I will keep nuking it from Parity.

Comment: @5chdn If it is spam, then it cost them a few thousand $ worth of gas to do the spamming right?

Comment: No, they don't distribute it to you account, they just display a default balance for any account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really think they are worth having, you can transfer them from any address you control to any other address you control - for example you can send them from an address to the same address as below.

Here's how I sent 1.00 SIM to myself on MyEtherWallet (this is 100 base tokens). It doesn't matter how many as long as it is 10000.00 or less - you'll end up with 10000.00 tokens whatever.  (If you send them to a different address, the receiving address will also be credited with 10000.00 tokens, I think.)

1. Triple check you are connected to the real MEW site - look for and check the EV-SSL status in the browser bar (Green padlock with "Secure" next it).
2. Unlock your account in the "Send Ether & Tokens" tab.
3. Add SIM as a custom token on the right:

   - Address: 0x86c8bF8532AA2601151c9DbbF4e4C4804e042571
   - Token Symbol: SIM
   - Decimals: 2
4. Copy and paste your Account Address to the "To Address" box. Check it is really correct. Check it is not the contract address above by mistake.
5. Put 1 in the "Amount to Send". Select SIM from the drop-down to the right of this box. Double check it says SIM.
6. In the top right drop down, change the Gas Price to 5 GWei or whatever works for you. This will take longer to process, but will save you Eth. Leave it at 21 if you are impatient. 5 Gwei took about 10 mins for me just now.
7. Create the transaction and follow through the rest of the process as usual.  Make sure the transfer is 0 ETH value before confirming it.
8. Wait for the transaction to be confirmed.

How do you know if your SIM tokens are now "real"? Well, you'll just have to trust the [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x86c8bf8532aa2601151c9dbbf4e4c4804e042571#code), at least until the cap is reached and all the phantom tokens vanish.

Comment: Of course, you can do all the above on Parity as well...